# Named route in Django cannot be reversed in template

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a simple named route:

```
url(r'^$', 'appname.views.static.home', name='homepage'),
```

and am trying to use this in a view:

```
{% url 'homepage' %}
```

So far as I can tell, this is correct according to the [docs on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) - so why do I get a `NoReverseMatch` error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the example in the documentation, not using quotes in the `url` helper works:

```
{% url homepage %}
```

Comment: You linked the docs for the development version. If you are using Django <= 1.4.1 the docs show exactly [the syntax that worked for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#id2).

Comment: always take in count that documentation version matchs with your django version. in that case you linked the django development version (1.4.x).

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems Google always prefers the dev version of the docs